# Windows 10 VM Virtualbox on host Ubuntu 22.04, opacity of menus, bars, etc is transparent and very difficult to see anything

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine

[image: transparent]

How do I fix that?  I also had a problem of typing in the magnifying glass hanging until I moved the taskbar to the right from the bottom.

I allocated 8GB ram out of 20GB total available and 150GB hard disk space of which about 100GB remains.

It's on a Lenovo Ideapad Gaming 15AcH6 with Ryzen 5.

Comment: Try a traditional theme for Windows 10.  My own Windows 10 VM does not have transparent windows.

Comment: I chose the Windows theme and it's still transparent

Answer (score 0):

Transparency settings were on by default so I had to follow instructions here: https://www.thewindowsclub.com/change-transparency-settings-windows-10

> Launch the Settings app, then venture off to Personalization > Colors.
> Scroll down until you’ve come across something that says “More
> options,” then look for the words, “Transparency effects.”
>
> You’ll see the option to turn it off or turn it off. Once the button
> has been toggled, the changes will take effect right away. If this
> doesn’t happen, restart the computer, and you should now be good to
> go.